# Automatically clear sale price at the product edit page after sales countdown in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am not yet good enough in coding. I just want to automatically clear the input text field of the sale price in the product edit page in Woocommerce after the sales schedule countdown. Because I just noticed that the sale price still their after the sales countdown and I need to clear it out automatically to make my Flash Sale functionality work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the plugin you are using?
Actually the problem is in the plugin so deactivate the plugin and use any of the below
 **Finale Lite**
 **HurryTimer**
 
 **Sales Countdown Timer**

Comment: Great! Thanks bro!